# Swift 2.2: Value of type 'Element' (aka 'AnyObject') has no member 'objectID'

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, initialization

I have a block of code that seemed to work before the latest Swift 2.2 update, but now it doesn't work.  Below is the relevant excerpts of code.

```
        class Event {
        var eventObjectID:NSManagedObjectID?
        var eventDate:NSDate?
        var eventNotes:String?
        var eventType:String?

        init(eventObjectID: NSManagedObjectID, eventDate: NSDate, eventNotes: String, eventType: String) {
            self.eventObjectID = eventObjectID
            self.eventDate = eventDate
            self.eventNotes = eventNotes
            self.eventType = eventType
        }
    }


class EventsViewController: UIViewController {

        var eventsListArray:[Event] = [Event]()
        var selectedAquarium:Aquarium!
        var selectedFilters = [String]?()

        //Load Core Data into the noteListArray so that we can populate the table view.
        func setEventsListArray() {
            //Fetch all of the events from Core Data
            var results: NSArray = fetchFromCoreData("Event")

            //Sort the list so that the newest entries are on top
            let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "eventDate", ascending: false)
            results = results.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([sortDescriptor]) as NSArray

            //Find only the event entries that are related to this aquarium and match the selected filters
            if (results.count > 0) {
                for fetchResult in results {
                    let currentAquarium = fetchResult.valueForKey("aquarium") as! CoreDataAquarium

                    for selectedFilter in selectedFilters! {
                        let currentEventType = fetchResult.valueForKey("eventType") as! String

                        //Find only the events related to this aquarium and scrap the rest
                        if (currentAquarium.objectID == selectedAquarium.aquariumObjectID && currentEventType == selectedFilter) {

                            //"This event matches the filter..."

                            let newEvent:Event = Event(eventObjectID: fetchResult.objectID,
                                eventDate: fetchResult.valueForKey("eventDate") as! NSDate,
                                eventNotes: fetchResult.valueForKey("eventNotes") as! String,
                                eventType: fetchResult.valueForKey("eventType") as! String)

                            eventsListArray.append(newEvent)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("No results returned...")
            }
        }
}
```

I get the following two errors in the line where I initialize newEvent(near the end of the code):

- Use of undeclared type 'NSManagedObjectID'
- Value of type 'Element'
  (aka 'AnyObject') has no member 'objectID'

Do these errors have to do with the new Swift language update?  Or am I just missing something really obvious?

Comment: Did you forget to `import CoreData`?

Comment: Durn it....Yeah, I did.  Haha thanks!

Comment: I'll enter that as an actual answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inability of the compiler to recognize the term NSManagedObject suggests that it doesn't know about the Core Data framework. You need to say

```
import CoreData
```

(typically at the very top of this file).

Answer (score 1):

As much as possible use Swift native collection types. `NSArray` is too unspecified. You don't need to cast the array to `NSArray` to be able to sort it.

```
//Fetch all of the events from Core Data
var results = fetchFromCoreData("Event")

//Sort the list so that the newest entries are on top
results.sortInPlace {($0.valueForKey("eventDate") as! NSDate).compare($1.valueForKey("eventDate") as! NSDate) == .OrderedDescending }
```

That probably solves the type problems.

PS: Consider to use a `NSManagedObject` subclass to get rid of all `valueForKey("...") as! ...` expressions

Comment: Looks like it was because I somehow deleted the import CoreData line by accident.  But you actually give some really useful advice and I am going to look into it and hopefully improve my code.  Thanks.

Comment: This answer is completely irrelevant to the problem the OP is actually having. It is also absolutely true! OP, you should definitely take this advice.

Comment: Have to downvote for `as!` (twice even).  It's highly unlikely you're a Jedi.

Comment: @nhgrif No offense, but optional binding for an attribute in the Core Data model which definitely exists is paranoid. The OP should consider to declare the attribute as non-optional because an event without a date is useless.

Comment: This isn't optional/forced *binding*.  This is *casting*.  You are force casting.  Maybe it is paranoid.  But there are two problems.  First, idiots touching the code base... and then changing the Core Data model out from under you.  Even if it's years after you've left the project, all of a sudden "This old legacy code is crashing.  Ugh."  Second, once you start using a linter to enforce never using `as!` (among other things), then this becomes annoying to deal with.

Comment: And that's all neverminding the fact that if a person like me is reviewing your code, I'm immediately going to stop and double check any force code like this.  Even if I determine it's okay, I end up spending more time than necessary looking at it.

Comment: The concept of Swift is: "Type safety is you don't need to check / care about types which never change at runtime". Do you check also at runtime if all forced unwrapped optional `IBOutlets` are connected or if all supporting files exist in the application bundle because *idiots touching ...*  ;-) Swift transfers more responsibility to the developer to care of those things and that's very good. The benefit is to get more efficient code.